# OpenLayers: Incorrect rendering of WKT

Tags: postgis, javascript, openlayers, well-known-text

I'm using the [draw function](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Draw-Draw.html) of OpenLayers for draw a polygon. I need the wkt from the drawn geometry because I need to send it to PostGIS.

```
  <textarea name="name" rows="20" cols="80"
            id="coordinates">
  </textarea>

draw.on('drawend', function(evt){
    var feature = evt.feature;
    tableSRID = 4326;
    epsg = 'EPSG:' + tableSRID;

    var format = new ol.format.WKT()
    wkt = format.writeGeometry(evt.feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:3857',epsg))
    console.log('Geometry\n' + wkt + '\n\n')

    completeWKT = 'SRID=' + tableSRID + ';' + wkt
    console.log('WKT with SRID\n' + completeWKT + '\n\n')
    document.getElementById('coordinates').innerHTML = completeWKT;

});
```

I can see correctly the `wkt` into the `console.log`, I've test it using [this service](https://arthur-e.github.io/Wicket/sandbox-gmaps3.html). The problem cames at the end of the draw because I see on the map the geometry with epsg 4326 instead of 3857.

This is one of polygons that I've drawn:

> MULTIPOLYGON(((1400149.5641348532 5271139.432674438,1373243.7301784712
>   5211824.298725141,1452126.7433687733 5203874.847783483,1465579.6603469641 5288261.327010318,1400149.5641348532 5271139.432674438)))

and this is the projected polygon from `wkt`:

> MULTIPOLYGON(((12.577757535156248
>   42.731151168561155,12.336058316406248 42.33852359891077,13.04467648046875 42.28571587692704,13.165526089843748 42.84402771111729,12.577757535156248 42.731151168561155)))

I see on the map the first MULTIPOLYGON and not his reprojection from wkt.

How I can solve?

**NB**: *I never yet implemented the code for send the wkt to PostGIS, I need to find a solution using Django Rest Framework GIS. But this is another question.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must either clone the geometry before transforming it, or you can specify projections as options to writeGeometry

either

```
wkt = format.writeGeometry(evt.feature.getGeometry().clone().transform('EPSG:3857',epsg))
```

or

```
wkt = format.writeGeometry(evt.feature.getGeometry(), {dataProjection: epsg, featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});
```

Comment: Thank you! What do you think is better? They are equivalent solutions and both working fine.